# transfer jpg file from server to client - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, server, client

I'm trying to send a screenshot (using PIL) from the server to the client.

The screenshot part works fine, but when i try to send the image it doesn't work. When I try to create the image, the file is not created. I think the problem is the way I send the data.

I read that I have to send the file size to the client before transfering the file, but i didn't understand how to do that.

server:

```
import socket
from random import randint
from PIL import ImageGrab

SIZE = 1024


def main():


while True:
    try:
        server_socket = socket.socket()
        server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8820))
        server_socket.listen(1)
        (client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
        data = client_socket.recv(1024)

        if data == "SCREEN":
            image = ImageGrab.grab()
            image.save(r'C:\Users\Dennis\Desktop\Python\ScreenShots\screen.jpg')

            file = open('C:\Users\Dennis\Desktop\Python\ScreenShots\screen.jpg', 'rb')
            content = file.read()

            while content:
                current = content[:SIZE]
                content = content[SIZE:]
                client_socket.send(current)

            file.close()

        if data == "EXIT":
            client_socket.send("Disconnected")
            break

        else:
            print "error"


    # in case client disconnected
    except socket.error:
        print "Connection was lost."

    client_socket.close()
    server_socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

client:

```
import socket


def main():

while True:
    my_socket = socket.socket()
    my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8820))
    my_socket.send(raw_input())

    content = ''
    while True:
        data = my_socket.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        content += data

        with open ('C:\Users\screennew.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(content)


    if data == "Disconnected":
        break

my_socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thank you very much, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: you're playing with fire not prefixing your path strings with `r`. In python 3 `\U` has a meaning and your program won't work at all.

Comment: can you try writing like this: `with open('C:\Users\screennew.jpg', 'wb') as f: f.write(content)`. That will ensure that file is closed propery.

Comment: I changed the code now, the infinite loop was the problem, thank you both for your help.